# Why does this JPQL fail with message "You have attempted to set a parameter at position 1 which does not exist in this query string"?

Tags: java, jpa

I have an interface extending `JpaRepository` containing this update query defined like that:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE configuration SET id = replace(id, ?1, ?2) WHERE id LIKE ?3")
void updateId(String replaceThis, String replaceWith, String like);
```

I get always "`You have attempted to set a parameter at position 1 which does not exist in this query string UPDATE configuration SET id = replace(id, ?1, ?2) WHERE id LIKE ?3`" error message which I don't understand because parameter at position 1 clearly exists where I put it. What am I missing?

Comment: Read this, specifically the section "ordinal parameters" https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter#Ordinal_Parameters_index If you have any problem, post your method implementation.

Comment: @JLazar0 I did. I use the @Query "bean" to use the query as it is, there is no further implementation of `updateId`.

Comment: If you change the query to "UPDATE configuration SET id = replace (id,:replaceThis,:replaceWith) WHERE id LIKE :like" and before each parameter of the method you add @Param ("replaceThis") ... works? is to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I also tried with named parameters yesterday but it didn't work. I will try again. I know somehow suspect that "replace" function is the problem... I am not sure wheter JPQL understands "replace".

Comment: you can try this query @Query("UPDATE configuration SET id = function('replace',id, ?1, ?2) WHERE id LIKE ?3")?

Comment: @JLazar0 THANKS! please provide this comment as solution so that I can mark is as the answer. I've never known about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this query:

```
   @Query("UPDATE configuration SET id = function('replace',id, ?1, ?2) WHERE id LIKE ?3")?
```